# Mocking response with 2 variables using SoapUi

Tags: xpath, soapui

Is it possible to check two or more variables when mocking a response using SoapUi?

Here's a sample of the request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:crm="http://www.example.com/project/wsdl/crm/">
   <soap:Body>
   <crm:SearchCustomer>
     <FirstName>Francis</FirstName>
     <LastName>Zabala</LastName>
   </crm:SearchCustomer>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here's the Extract Xpath

```
declare namespace crm='http://www.example.com/project/wsdl/crm/';
declare namespace soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope';
//crm:SearchCustomer[1]/FirstName
```

Expected value:

```
Francis
```

What about if I also want to check the last name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the follow *XPath* expression which check for the text content of the `<FirstName>` and `<LastName>` and use `boolean()` XPath function to check if the expression it's accomplished or not. Also SOAPUI supports the use of `*` as a wildcard for namespaces so your expression could be:

```
boolean(//*:FirstName[text() = 'Francis'] and //*:LastName[text() = 'Zabala'])
```

And as expected value:

```
true
```

Comment: I didn't expect that you could evaluate in the xpath and use the expected value. Nice. Thanks!

Comment: @FrancisZabala nice to help you :)